# How to get First element from a map that includes something?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to select the first path directory from the api that includes an Image so I can set the value to the Image source and display the first image but when i use fl[0] i get all values

here is the code :

```
{useLesson &&
            useLesson.files.map((fl, index) => {
               
                if (fl.mimetype.includes("image")) {
               // this always get all values not only the first value
                console.log(fl[0])
               // and this always gives me infinite loop issue
                setSelectedImage(fl[0])
                    return (
                        <div key={index}>
                                <img  src={axiosUse + fl.path} alt="" />
                        </div>

                    )
                }
            })
        }
```

How can I get only the first value from a map that includes something inside it ?

what I am trying to do is getting files from the server and if its an image file then display some component but how can I get only the first Image value file ?

Comment: Is this the body code of function setSelectedImage?

Comment: yes its a state that i want to store the first value of the image to it

Comment: I'm assuming that's in your JSX. You shouldn't be setting state like that inside your JSX. What's happening is you're rendering the component, returning the JSX but also setting the state inside it which re-renders the component, sets state again, re-renders, sets state, re-renders etc. If you're getting files from the server that needs to be managed by [a `useEffect` hook](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html) with an empty dependency array. You can then map over that data in a function, add that information to state, and then finally render the JSX with that state.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create a new component to show the first file

```js
const FilePreview = ({ mimetype, files, basepath }) => {
  const firstFileOfType = files.find((file) =>
    file.mimetype.includes(mimetype)
  );
  if (!firstFileOfType) return null;

  return (
    <div>
      <img src={basepath + firstFileOfType.path} alt="" />
    </div>
  );
};
```

and use it as

```
  {useLesson && (
    <FilePreview
      mimetype="image"
      files={useLesson.files}
      basepath={axiosUse}
    />
  )}
```

Comment: its working great , i am a bit confused from how is this working but can you explain how does this work ?

Comment: So, the important part is the `files.find((file) => file.mimetype.includes(mimetype));`. This finds (and returns) the first element in the array that has the specified `mimetype`. Then the component uses that element only for rendering. Keep in mind that `FilePreview` is a standalone component. You should define outside of the original component you were using.

Comment: thank you for the explanation , i need to focus more on outside components its so useful :)